# most efficient method of chaining 2 data sets in laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, join, laravel-query-builder

Now you can blast me if I'm asking the question too specifically, saying Laravel, but I'm wondering, what is the most efficient way of chaining 2 data sets together with the tools within Laravel.

Is there a specific mindset I should be using when picking  between using eloquent relationships and joins with query builder? Or any drawbacks to using query builder on smaller or larger datasets that I should consider?

I'm building a ticket system that would only need one or 2 fields from the user table and it seems very over the top to consider using a relationship at this point but if the needs of the system increases, it could lead to messy code. Is this the situation that the relationships are there to solve?

Is there any coupling type action happening when using eloquent relationships that I should be aware of?

If I'm really not being clear with how I'm asking the question I will try and reword it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll find as I did that setting up a couple simple relationship methods in your Eloquent model unleashes the power (and thus the ease and simplicity) of Eloquent. For example, would you rather write custom join code or use a structure like this:

```
foreach($user->tickets as $ticket) { ... etc ... }
```

It sounds like you're very new to Laravel. I highly recommend reading the pages on relationships in the [Laravel manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships). There are many great examples. Also there is a Laracast video tutorial on Relationships [here](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/14). I have no affiliation to this site.

Ticket class:

```
<?php
class Ticket extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

User class:

```
<?php
class User extends Model {
    public function tickets() {
        return $this->hasMany('Ticket');
    }
}
```

so long as you have a tables setup like so:

```
tickets (table)
- id
- user_id

users (table)
- id
```

This example assumes the models are in the global namespace. Then you can grab user data from a ticket like so:

```
$ticket->user->first_name
$ticket->user->last_name
```

Comment: I hasten to add that I have read the information on eloquent and its uses to a fairly large extent.I totally see your point and I guess that I always knew that there is an eventual upside. But surely there is also a downside to it as well? The example used in my case is such  that  the needs of this system are literally 2 fields from my user table to be needed in every request for a ticket and that is it. I guess I'm trying to gauge the point at which the need for each would divide itself. If there are 0 drawbacks to using these relationships then absolutely i would use it exsclusively.

Comment: There are no drawbacks to using the relationships built into Laravel. If they seem like too much trouble I assure you it is only because they are unfamiliar to you. This relationship between users and tickets is extremely simplistic:
- Users haveMany tickets
- Tickets belongTo one User

Comment: I added an example implementation to the answer.

Comment: Technically, you do not need to implement the reverse relationship on the User class since you're querying from the Ticket object.

Comment: Good example, I think i can kind  of see why it seems like an  unreasonable question now, but i assure you, your answer is just the answer i was after. No drawback = default choice for me